# EL JSP não funciona

Tags: java, jsp

Código do Servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    token = "teste";
    request.setAttribute("token", token);
    System.out.println(token);
    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("teste.jsp");
    view.forward(request, response);     
}
```

Trecho que eu quero imprimir o parâmetro:

```html
<p>Primeiro token adicionado é : $(requestScope.token) </p>
```

Ao invés de imprimir o conteúdo do atributo ele imprime `$(requestScope.token)`.

Answer (score 4):

Você fez o atribuição para o valor `token`:

```
request.setAttribute("token", token);
```

Já testou com `<p>Primeiro token adicionado é : ${token} </p>`?

Atente-se para o uso de `{}`.

https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-web/javaserver-pages/#6-5-misturando-codigo-java-com-html

Obs: Lembrado que deve ser feito o passo mencionado pelo Lucas Costa: Importar a as taglib no cabeçalho da sua JSP.